# Unable to see RabbitMQ Queue information in ELK

Tags: elasticsearch, rabbitmq, kibana, elastic-stack, elk

I have ELK set up as a service from Microsoft Azure. Using AKS with pods running RabbitMQ, and the elastic agent

I want to see the RabbitMQ queue data in the ELK dashboards.

Added the integration for RabbitMQ, with the details for the RabbitMQ service at port 15672, with the correct credentials. Included the Queue stream

Within the default dashboard for RabbitMQ it is showing me that I have 3 RabbitMQ nodes - this is correct.

The issue I am having is that I am not able to see any other data about the queues.

I have added the field: rabbitmq.queue.messages.total.count but this is showing nothing at all. I am not sure if the queue data is coming through or not but I am guessing that if the node data is coming through, then the set up is fine.

When I add the field to the dashboard: rabbitmq.queue.name - it gives me queue names relating to: amq.gen, which are not the names of my queues.

I know that the management plugin is enabled
I am able to see the queues from the elastic pods when hitting /api/queues

Please can I get some guidance as to what i'm missing here.

Thank you